# How to get, read, retrieve preferences from Selenium Firefox Webdriver?

Tags: vb.net, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've seen many examples of [how setting Firefox preferences with Selenium Webdriver by creating a profile](https://seleniumbycharan.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/how-to-use-firefox-profile-preferences-in-selenium-webdriver/). My question is: how can I read preferences already set while using an already created instance of FirefoxDriver? I'm using .NET port of WebDriver. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom preferences are stored in `user.js` in the profile.

So you can get them by reading `user.js` from the current session:

```csharp
ICapabilities capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;
string prefs_path = (string)capabilities.GetCapability("moz:profile") + "\\user.js";
```